# JAVA Decryption error: Needs Input to be multiple of 16

Tags: java, encryption, key-generator

I'm trying to develop a simple encryption/decryption program.  The problem I am running into is when I attempt to decrypt the encrypted message, I get an error message stating that the Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with cipher.  I read somewhere that the encrypted message might need to be encoded before converting it to a string.  I'm not sure how to do this?  Or if there is an alternative way can someone please help me out?

```
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;


public class Cryption {
    public static void cryption(String[] args, String message) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        byte[] encodedKey = "ADBSJHJS12547896".getBytes();
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        Key aesKey = keyGen.generateKey();

        System.out.println("CheckType: "+ Global.checkType);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        byte[] input = Global.message.getBytes();

        // Check if clicked Encrypted
        if(Global.checkType==true) {
            // Encrypt
            byte[] messageEncrypted = cipher.doFinal(input);
            System.out.println("Encrypted Text: " + messageEncrypted);
            Global.encValue = messageEncrypted.toString();
        }

        // Check if clicked Decrypted
        if(Global.checkType==false) {
            //String mes = message;
            System.out.println(Global.message);
            System.out.println("Char lenght " + Global.message.length());
            byte[] mesByte = Global.message.getBytes();


            // Decrypt
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            byte[] messageDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(mesByte);
            System.out.println("Text Decrypted: " + new String(messageDecrypted));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Global.encValue = messageEncrypted.toString();
```

This is completely wrong, as it just calls byte[].toString(), which doesn't give you the contents, just a thing with a classname and a hashcode in it. It is also wrong semantically, as String is not a container for binary data in the first place. Don't turn encrypted text into a String. Use the byte[] array that the API gave you.

Comment: I need to turn the data into a string because the GUI of this program has a textfield in which a user can input some text (say a encrypted message).  So if you originally encrypt the data, it's suppose to spit out the encrypted message into the field.  And then I want to be able to decrypt the data from the same field and have it spit out the decrypted message.  Sorry for the confusion and sorry if my logic doesn't make sense as I am new to programming.

Comment: @scriptdiddy Typing encrypted data into a text field doesn't make any sense to me but if that's a real use-case you will have to base64-encode it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html

It probably means that it doesn't know if it is ASCII or UTF8 or some other byte encoding...

Comment: It was worse than that, it never send the cipher text at all, see the answer of EJP